# How to convert JSON into excel file with multisheet?

Tags: python, json, excel, csv, xls

I have a set of 300+ JOSN files like location_X.json, location_Y.json,... and so on with structure like in file location_X.json I have

```
 {"Cardiologist": [{"name": "Dr. AB", "url": "https://www....-cardiologist?specialization=Cardiologist", "photo": [], "image": "https://images1-....jpg/thumbnail", "address": {"addressLocality": "location_X", "addressRegion": "delhi", "@type": "PostalAddress"}, "branchOf": {"url": "https://www....-clinic-x-y-market", "address": {"addressLocality": "X.Y.Market", "addressRegion": "delhi", "@type": "PostalAddress"}, "@type": "MedicalClinic", "name": "Dr AB Clinic"}, "priceRange": 0, "openingHours": [], "currenciesAccepted": "INR", "@context": "http://schema.org/", "geo": {"latitude": "", "@type": "GeoCoordinates", "longitude": ""}, "@type": "Physician", "medicalSpecialty": "Cardiologist"}], ... }
```

You can think of structure like this:

```
{"Specialty_1":[{"name":"","url":"", "photo":"", "address":{"addressLocality": "", "addressRegion": "", "@type": "PostalAddress"},"branchOf": {"url": "https://www...", "address": {"addressLocality": "", "addressRegion": "", "@type": "PostalAddress"},"@type": "MedicalClinic", "name": "Dr AB Clinic"}, "priceRange": 0, "openingHours": [], "currenciesAccepted": "", "@context": "http://schema.org/", "geo": {"latitude": "", "@type": "GeoCoordinates", "longitude": ""}, "@type": "Physician", "medicalSpecialty": "Specialty_1"}, ...], "Specialty_2":[{"name":"","photo":"", ...}, ...], ... }
```

Dictionary with list of all doctors of particular specialty in particular area with 13-types of features and consists of all doctors in that area,

How do I convert this JSON file such that I get a file for location_X in Excel with multisheet with each sheet named like "Specialty_1", "Specialty_2", and so on... containing all doctors for "Specialty_1" etc in the location X.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may try Pandas. Its documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/

Basically, what you should do is:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
json_data = json.load(open('<your_json_file>'))
data = pd.read_json(json_data)
excel_file = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
data.to_excel(writer, 'sheet1')
writer.save()
```

This code above saves the jsonified data into the sheet named 'sheet1' in output.xlsx. If you want to save data in different sheets, you may process your data first, dividing them into different jsonified data. And then call `to_excell` function to save them into different sheets respectively.

Comment: Thanks for this quick reply. I think you almost solved the problem am facing but I have 145 kinds of specialty for doctors in my JSON file. If I try of dividing them I might end up with 300*145 ~ 40k JSON files in the worst case. There must be some workaround for making multisheet :)

Comment: @ShivamAgrawal You don't have to actually save json data into json files. You may simply put your data in the memory and then manipulate them. If you save your data into files, it causes lots of trouble and you'll have to open the files one by one.

Comment: @ShivamAgrawal what I am suggesting is that you may uses `json.loads` function to convert json data into python built-in datatype data. Then you may do any operation you want on them. In this case, you divide them into several categories. After that, you use `json.dumps` function to convert the processed data into jsonified data and write them into excel file.